# Work done by a force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, definition

What is the difference between work done by a force and work done against that force?

Is it true that work by a force = -(work against that force)?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much. Although the sign of work depends exactly on who is doing work to whom. For example, if you compress a spring, you work against the force of the spring, thereby increasing its energy. When the spring extends back towards its relaxed length, its energy decreases and leaves the spring as mechanical work.